# MySqlConnectionStringBuilder - Connect with Certificates

Tags: c#, mysql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

Iam trying to connect to Google Cloud Sql which is a MySql solution. I was able to connect using MySql Workbench.

How can i connect in c# using the `MySqlConnectionStringBuilder`?

I found no way to provide the three certificate(s).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution.

1. Make sure you gain access to external connection using the google cloud console + you have to set a password.
2. Export the 3 certificate files
3. Create a new certificate using

   ```
   openssl pkcs12 -export -in client-cert.pem -inkey client-key.pem 
                  -certfile server-ca.pem -out client.pfx
   ```
4. Source Code

   ```
       var connectionStringBuilder = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder
       {
           Server = "<Instance_Ip>",
           UserID = "root",
           Password = "<Password>",
           Database = "<Database_Name>",
           CertificateFile = @"<Path_To_The_File>\client.pfx",
           CertificatePassword = "<Password_For_The_Cert>"
       };

       using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionStringBuilder.ToString()))
       using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
       {    
           cmd.CommandText = string.Format("SELECT * FROM test");
           conn.Open();
           var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
           while (reader.Read())
           {
               var data = reader.GetString(0);
               Console.WriteLine(data);
           }
       }
   ```