# How to use ip-address with username in connection string?

Tags: c#, mysql, database, connection, database-connection

I wrote this method, but it throws System.ArgumentException if "uid" has ' symbols in.

```
        public void Init(string constr)
            {
                var server = "a222068_6.mysql.mchost.ru";
                var database = "'a222068_6'";
                var uid = "'a222068_6'@'10.0.2.13'";
                var pass = "pass";

                constr = "SERVER=" + server + ";DATABASE=" + database + ";UID=" + uid + ";PASSWORD=" + pass + ";SSL Mode=None;";
                cnt = new MySqlConnection(constr); // Exception is thrown here
            }
```

Exception message on attempt to connect without '

```
Authentication to host 'a222068_6.mysql.mchost.ru' for user 'a222068_6@10.0.2.13' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Access denied for user 'a222068_6@10.0.2.13'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Comment: You should use MySqlConnectionStringBuilder  to do that automatically.

Comment: Just from my head, `";UID=\"" + uid + "\";PASSWORD="` should work, however as said above the MySqlConnectionStringBuilder class should fix potential quoting problems automatically.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work too. Or i probably using MySqlConnectionStringBuilder in wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
var uid = "'a222068_6'@'10.0.2.13'";
```

to

```
var uid = @"a222068_6@10.0.2.13";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [verbatim string literal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/string):

> Verbatim string literals start with @ and are also enclosed in double quotation marks.

And there are several other StackOverflow answers with examples of how to use MySqlConnectionStringBuilder, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39031653/1964690):

```
var connectionStringBuilder = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder
{
    Server = "<instanceIp>",
    UserID = "<userId>",
    Password = "<password>",
    Database = "<databaseName>",
    CertificateFile = @"<Path_To_The_File>\client.pfx",
    CertificatePassword = "<Password_For_The_Cert>"
};

var conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionStringBuilder.ToString())
```